# Вопрос по std::map::erase()

Tags: c++, map

есть mymap
если его вывести то получим

```
0) а
1) б
2) в
```

после mymap.erase(1);

на выводе получаю

```
0) а
2) в
```

а хотел бы получать

```
0) а
1) в
```

есть метод в  библиотеке который уберет пробел в порядке чисел и отсортирует ключи по возрастанию? или как это можно сделать по другому?

Comment: Как я понял, использование карты вместо вектора обусловлено автоматической сортировкой. Если это так, то можно воспользоваться, например, std::set. Остается еще тогда вопрос, а так уж нужны ли ключи, если они могут быть изменены? Если они нужны только для вывода, то я бы на них вообще "забил".

Comment: @MaxZS по ключу юзер вызывает юнита с мэпа. при убийстве юнита, я удаляю юнита с мэпа и тут при выборе следующего юнита происходила проблема, но я решал обыграть ситуацию, и при смерти юнита просто менял его имя на Dead, убрал возможность играть этим юнитом и убрал его с карты и по окончанию игры просто удаляю всех.

Comment: Ну так у юнита тогда должны быть уникальные ключи, как я понял. Если ключ не уникальный, то, по большому счету, он и не нужен. У меня была похожая проблема и приходилось перебирать всю карту и сравнивать значения. Меня это очень сильно напрягало до тех пор, пока я не взял и не протестировал затраты на перебор, сравнение и удаление при этом всех значений по одному начиная с начала карты (именно с начала). Так вот, я сам удивился насколько мизерными оказались затраты даже при 50000 элементов в карте. При том, что тестовую карту я создавал исключительно с рандомными значениями.

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле достаточно использовать `set<char>` пример вашего кода

```
set<char> s;
s.insert('a');
s.insert('b');
s.insert('c');
auto ps = s.begin();
for (auto i=0;ps!=s.end();ps++,i++)
    cout << i<<" "<<*ps<<endl;
s.erase('b');
ps = s.begin();
cout << endl;
for (auto i=0;ps!=s.end();ps++,i++)
    cout << i<<" "<<*ps<<endl;
```

Если нужно выводить всё и сразу. Если нет то смотреть ниже.

Внимание! Работает только в gcc

```
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

typedef
tree<
  int,  //!
  null_type,
  less<int>, //!
  rb_tree_tag,
  tree_order_statistics_node_update>
ordered_set;

ordered_set t;
```

Можно написать например так

```
t.insert(0);
t.insert(1);
t.insert(2);
cout << t.order_of_key(2)<<endl;
t.erase(1);
cout << t.order_of_key(2)<<endl;
```

Правильный вывод: 2 1.

Int дан для примера, можно использовать любые типы. Это если нужны операции поиска по номеру (`*t.find_by_order(i)`) и нахождение номера по элементу.

Answer (score 2):

Такого метода нет, делать придётся руками. Для таких целей `std::map` не подходит — ключи менять нельзя, придётся всё удалять и заново вставлять.

Я бы выбрал `std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>`:

1. Храним вектор пары значений: (число, символ)
2. Сортируем вектор по ключу(число)
3. Когда удаляем элемент, то просто выполняем декремент для всех элементов, что идут за удалённым ключом.

Можно так же обратить внимание на `std::list`, в том случае, если вектор покажет плохую производительность из-за частых удалений(но это сомнительно)

Comment: Судя по примерам ТС, будет достаточно просто вектора символов.

Comment: @alexolut, да, в частном случае будет достаточно

Comment: `std::map<int, char> ` чем не подходит?

Comment: @avp "ключ" должен меняться